# npm outdated output colour-coding meaning

Tags: node.js, git, bash, npm

I run git command `npm outdated` in bash on a mac.

See the output in the image below.

Does anyone know why the first four packages are printed in red?

I guess it's because I have them pointing to github repos in my package.json, but why the red?

Is it a warning? Should I worry?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I also get red colored output for packages that are not pointed at git (i.e. normal npm target:  ![screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/kys7X).  And still no explanation on the npm docs as to what the colors mean.

Comment: There's a new issue on the npm cli for this, which might result in an official answer one day: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16224

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to be careful when depending on packages that are Github-hosted: if you're just pointing to the `master` branch of a package (which is the default when adding such dependencies), you can get in all sorts of trouble when that branch is updated and it's either not functional (it happens) or it breaks backward compatibility (that happens too).

I think this is what `npm` is trying to tell you.

FWIW, you should always include an identifier to a particular commit/tag/sha when you're dealing with Github-hosted dependencies. See [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) for more documentation. Although I doubt that `npm` won't also mark these URL's as red, because it's still possible for any of those identifiers to get invalidated.

**EDIT**: perhaps not quite.

Looking at it a little closer, it'll show the package name in red if the installed version doesn't (semver-)match the required version as set in `package.json`. In case of Github-hosted packages these will probably *never* match, hence the red.

Yellow is used when the installed version matches the required version, but there's a more recent version available in the NPM repository.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Still I couldn't find a clear explanation of the colours in the npm docs.

Comment: @Ursus see my edit, it may be a bit more subtle than I initially thought :-)

Comment: @Ursus there is a description in the `npm outdated` docs now - see the [other answer here from Andre Viera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689442/andre-gomes-borges-vieira)

Answer (score 15):

> Due to SemVer ^x.y.z caret format, red colors clearly indicate that packages are out of date, and they need to be upgraded. And yellow ones indicate that packages are out of date as well, but to upgrade, there might be breaking changes....
>
> All packages in red should be upgraded first, then upgrade ones in yellow, because of the possibility of breaking change.

https://realguess.net/2014/12/13/update-outdated-npm-packages/

Answer (score 15):

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-outdated#description

> 1. Red means there’s a newer version matching your semver requirements, so you should update now.
> 2. Yellow indicates that there’s a newer version *above* your semver requirements (usually new major, or new 0.x minor) so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 7):

Update - as of 2/27/2019
I had the same problem, moved to yarn and got the following:

```
> yarn outdated
yarn outdated v1.13.0
info Color legend :
 "<red>"    : Major Update backward-incompatible updates
 "<yellow>" : Minor Update backward-compatible features
 "<green>"  : Patch Update backward-compatible bug fixes

...
```

Please read the small letters... red is **backward-incompatible**
Npm follows the same color semantics.

Unlike the answers above, all outdated packages can be updated. This is a project specific upgrade policy decision.

Hope that helps

Comment: `yarn outdated` has more readable results unlike `npm outdated`. Using yarn for the info.